# How to add animation on owlCarousel slider contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

How to animate each content layer with selected css animation with owlCarousel slide?

Here what I did, but I can't make it work properly.

HTML

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="slide-item-1">
        <div class="layer layer1">
            <div data-animate="animated fadeInLeft">
                <h1>I'm layer 1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="layer layer2">
            <div data-animate="animated fadeInLeft">
                <h2>I'm layer 2</h2>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide-item-2">
        <div class="layer layer1">
            <div data-animate="animated fadeInLeft">
                <h1>I'm layer 1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="layer layer2">
            <div data-animate="animated fadeInLeft">
                <h2>I'm layer 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="layer layer3">
            <div data-animate="animated fadeInLeft">
                <h2>I'm layer 3</h2>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items:1,
        dots: true,
        nav: false,
        animateOut: 'fadeOutLeft',
        animateIn: 'fadeInRight',
        autoplay:true,
        onTranslated: animateSlide,
        onTranslate: removeAnimation
    });

    function removeAnimation() {
        var item = $(".owl-item .layer");
        item.removeClass(item.children().data('animate'));
    }

    function animateSlide() {
        var item = $(".owl-item.active .layer");
        item.addClass(item.children().data('animate'));
    }
});
```

Now I have this issues,

1. It shows content first and then animate, I mean contents don't come with animated, it comes first then animate.
2. First slide 'layer' DIV content don't animate content in first view but good after come back from other slides..
3. Last slide 'layer' DIV content animation works on first time view but next time don't work. What I can see is it add double animation or don't remove animation class after slide to another.
4. Middle slides are working fine without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different [events](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html) of the owl-carousel where you can bind [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) animations to.

In the example I used the `change.owl.carousel` event:

> #### change.owl.carousel
>
> Type: `attachable`
> Callback: `onChange`
> Parameter: `property`
> When a property is going to change its value.

The function itself adds the animation class ([`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)) and removes it again after the animation end is triggered ([`one(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) followed by [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)).

```js
var owl = $('.custom1').owlCarousel({
    animateOut: 'slideOutDown',
    animateIn: 'flipInX',
    items:1,
    margin:30,
    stagePadding:30,
    smartSpeed:450,
    loop: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
});

owl.on('change.owl.carousel', function (event) {
    var el = event.target;
    $('h4', el).addClass('slideInRight animated')
            .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
                $('h4', el).removeClass('slideInRight animated');
            });
        });
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/css/docs.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<section id="demos">
<div class="custom1 owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item"><h4>1</h4>
  </div><div class="item"><h4>2</h4>
  </div><div class="item"><h4>3</h4>
  </div><div class="item"><h4>4</h4>
  </div><div class="item"><h4>5</h4>
  </div><div class="item"><h4>6</h4>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```